# Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException' with message 'Failed connect to api.twilio.com:443

Tags: php, curl, twilio

Hi I am trying to send sms with Twilio api, It works on their web-sites but doesn't work on my local server here is my code.

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "I wrote my Sid(test sid also doesn't work)"; 
$token = "my token"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$sms = $client->account->sms_messages->create("From","To","Jenny     please?! I love you <3", array());

?>
```

When I run this code I get : Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_TinyHttpException' with message 'Failed connect to api.twilio.com:443; No error' in ....

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

This sounds like a common issue where your version of libcurl which cannot validate the certificate Twilio is offering to it.

There are several different work-arounds you can try documented here:

https://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

check that your server's `port:443` is open or close?

check it here 
http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

If the port is closed, open it and your code will work.

It worked for me. Good Luck!